# VB.NET & SQL Server 2012 : thread 1 writing to a table while thread 2 reads from the same table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a VB.NET application with two separate background workers.

BG1 connects to a stored procedure, which, as the script progresses, writes out information to Table A.

BG2, contained within a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, in the same application, will retrieve the records from Table A and display them in a ListView.

Table A schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IMPORT.DBO.XXX_ANALYSIS_UPDATES 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
    [GROUPING] VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, 
    SOURCE VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, 
    TARGET VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, 
    [TYPE] VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, 
    ACTION VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, 
    COUNTS INT NOT NULL
)
```

When I run this, it is taking over one minute for the below query to execute

```
SELECT * 
FROM IMPORT.DBO.XXX_ANALYSIS_UPDATES
```

It's likely this is because I am constantly writing to the table IN BG1, while trying to extract the data in BG2.

Is there a way to get around this lag so I can report on the "progress" from Table A in the VB.NET ListBox "while" inserts are being made into Table A?

Table A, at the most, will contain 100 records.

Comment: I would suggest dumping the "timer".... and using "binding" ::: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: This is one situation where using ` with (nolock)` is valid...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you stumble across the answer...

Basically, I had to have a separate connection to the same database in the BG and everything works exactly as expected.

Comment: Good that you've answered your question but just an IMO _Basically, I had to have a separate connection_.  This should be the case anyway.  Create your connections with Using clause, do the job and get out letting Using clean up and dispose of your connection objects keeping it all nice and isolated.

Comment: In this particular application, the connection is open until the application closes.  I didnt design the application.  I just add additional features from time to time.